# How to return comma and pipe delimited strings containing the values of the properties of a C# object?

Tags: c#, reflection, tostring

```
    var flags = System.Reflection.BindingFlags.Instance | System.Reflection.BindingFlags.Public | **strong text**System.Reflection.BindingFlags.FlattenHierarchy;
    System.Reflection.PropertyInfo[] infos = this.GetType().GetProperties(flags);



    StringBuilder sb = new StringBuilder();
   
    string typeName = this.GetType().Name;
    
    foreach (var info in infos)
    {
        object value = info.GetValue(this, null);

        sb.AppendFormat("{0}={1},{2}", info.Name, value != null ? value : "null",Environment.NewLine);
        
    }
    sb.Length -= 2;
    return sb.ToString().Substring(0, sb.Length - 1);
}
```

I have tried the above logic , but its returning like "name = john", "id= 23". But I need to display like "name","id" and then "john","23".

Comment: You will need to either iterate infos twice, firstly collecting the names, then collect the values on the second, or append the names and values to two different Stringbuilders and combine their outputs at the end of the loop.

Answer (score 0):

I am not sure where your data is at namely infos
But here is some code I use to populate a DataGridView the data is in a SQLite Database table but it is added to a Generic list of objects

```
       public void loadDGV()
    {
        frmCRUD form = new frmCRUD();
        {
            form.readData(list);
            for (int index = 0; index < list.Count - 2; index += 3)
            {
                dgvPerson.Rows.Add(list[index], list[index + 1], list[index + 2]);
            }
            dgvPerson.Sort(dgvPerson.Columns[2], ListSortDirection.Ascending);
        }
    }
```